# Use camera in Landscape only app -iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have an application that supports only landscape mode. When I opening the camera the app crashes. I solved the problem by using the following code.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

But the app turns to support all orientations. All I want is the app only support landscape mode and also uses camera.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you try this :
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate 
{
    return [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] !=      UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

Comment: check with bellow code..
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        return YES;

    return NO;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The shouldAutorotate never gets called in ViewControllers. Because the topmost view controller has to return the interface orientations it wants to rotate to. In my case, that's the UINavigationController. So I creates the new category for UINavigationController to make it work. I uses the following methods in the category

```
@implementation UINavigationController (BugiOSFix)

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this For orientations .........

```
   -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
      [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
      [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation duration:1.0];

      UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = 
             [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

      if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || 
         orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
           {
             [self setFrameForLeftAndRightOrientation];
            }
      else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait )
          {
             [self setFrameForPortraitAndUpsideDownOrientation];
          }
  }

     - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
                    (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                 duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
          {
             if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft 
              || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
              {
                [self setFrameForLeftAndRightOrientation];
              }
            else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
             {
                [self setFrameForPortraitAndUpsideDownOrientation];
             }

        }
   -(void)setFrameForLeftAndRightOrientation
       {
          if(IS_IPAD)
            { 
               // Write here for left and right orientation
             }
          else if(is_iPhone)
            {
                // Write here for iPhone land scape ;
             }

   -(void)setFrameForPortraitAndUpsideDownOrientation
             {
                 if(IS_IPAD)
                    {
                       // Write here for Portrait orientation for iPad
                     }
                 else if(is_iPhone)
                    {
                      // Write here for iPhone Portrait orientation ;
                     }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer at [How to create a landscape-view only ios application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822375/how-to-create-a-landscape-view-only-ios-application/20823029#20823029) for a similar question. All you have to do is to implement one method and your app will be forced to autorotate to the direction you want it.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

This will force your app to rotate to the `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` direction by providing your ViewController with only one preferred orientation.