# How to create a landscape-view only ios application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to create an iOS app that can only work on landscape-view mode.

I Googled how to do that, and end up with supportedInterfaceOrientations method

Here's my attempt:

```
    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

I tried to put the above code on viewController.m and AppDelegate.m, but it didn't seem to work

Thanks, any opinion will be much appreciated

Comment: You can go to plist file of your project and look for element "Supported interface orientations" which will be having four elements for all four orientations. Delete the ones that you don't need by clicking minus icon displayed on that line upon selection.

Comment: Click on the name of the project on the left side pane, then you should be able to see the general info of your app. Deselect the view rotation you don't want and the app will be landscape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to write any code to run app which supports landscape mode only. Just **select app target and uncheck portrait and portrait upside down orientation and make sure landscape orientation is checked.**

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you want to programmatically change the orientation of your application. This can be done by any ViewController by implementing one method.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

That should force the view to auto-rotate in the direction you want it.

When you use `-supportedInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` it simply states that the returned interfaces **can** be used, not necessarily that they **should be used**.

When you use `-preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` it says that this is orientation that I want, and that the ViewController **should** switch to it.